# how to remove numeric characters before any alphabetic characters

Tags: bash, sed

I have one variable which has values like this

```
VAL1="59809_RH_EA_TEST_1_P1_Q"
```

or

```
VAL1="89292-RH_EA_TEST_1_P1_Q"
```

How can I get only `RH_EA_TEST_1_P1_Q` using sed or any other bash command

Comment: I've voted to close this question because it appears to be a request for a recommendation for a tool or solution, rather than a request for assistance with your own code. This makes your question off-topic for StackOverflow. If that assessment was incorrect, and you do indeed want help writing your own code, then please [add your work so far to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43106869/edit) and I'll happily retract my close vote.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use Bash regex matching.

```
VAL1="59809_RH_EA_TEST_1_P1_Q"

if
  [[ $VAL1 =~ ^[0-9]+_(.*) ]]
then
  VAL1=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
fi
```

This assumes your numbers are always followed by an underscore.  If you want to avoid this assumption, you could use :

```
if
  [[ $VAL1 =~ ^[0-9]+_?(.*) ]]
then
  VAL1=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
fi
```

Bash regex matching works as a test (the `[[ =~ ]]` expression returns 0 if there is a match), and sub-expressions (defined in the matching string by using parentheses around the areas of interest) are available as elements in array `BASH_REMATCH`, starting at index 1.  Extended regular expressions are used.

In case anyone wonders, no double quoting is required anywhere in the above.  The `[[ ]]` is special shell syntax (not a command with arguments like the `[`/`test` command), no word splitting is performed inside.  The assignment also does not perform word splitting.

Comment: As an aside, please note that the double-bracket Bash test performs pattern matching when `=` and `!=` operators are used, unless the right-hand expression is quoted, so this is one case where quoting could actually be required (although not to prevent word splitting), as in many cases allowing pattern matching is not desired.

Answer (score 1):

With [Parameter Expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion)

```
$ VAL1='59809_RH_EA_TEST_1_P1_Q'
$ echo "${VAL1#*[_-]}"
RH_EA_TEST_1_P1_Q

$ VAL1='89292-RH_EA_TEST_1_P1_Q'
$ echo "${VAL1#*[_-]}"
RH_EA_TEST_1_P1_Q
```

- This removes minimal match from start of string upto first occurrence of `_` or `-`

Comment: This solution deviates a bit from the "remove digits" from beginning stated in the question, but if the actual strings fit well with this approach, it is nice and simple.  You could also remove digits with `shopt -s extglob ; VAL1=${VAL1##*([0-9])}` (or `VAL1=${VAL1##*([0-9])_}` to remove the underscore at the same time if you are sure it is always there).

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approaches:

```
VAL1="59809_RH_EA_TEST_1_P1_Q"
```

`sed` approach:

```
sed 's/^[^_-]*[_-]\(.*\)/\1/' <<< $VAL1
```

---

`cut` approach:

```
cut -d'_' -f2- <<< $VAL1
```

---

The output(for both approaches):

```
RH_EA_TEST_1_P1_Q
```

Answer (score 0):

With awk

```
#!/bin/sh

rnum () { # remove numeric characters before any alphabetic characters
 awk '
 function ch(i) { return substr(ARGV[1], i, 1) } # ith character
 BEGIN {
         a = "[a-zA-Z]" ; d = "[0-9]"
         n = length(ARGV[1]); i = 1
         for ( ; i <= n && ch(i) !~ a; i++) if (ch(i) !~ d) ans = ans ch(i)
         for ( ; i <= n              ; i++)                 ans = ans ch(i)
         print ans
       }
 ' "$1"
}

# usage
rnum 59809_RH_EA_TEST_1_P1_Q
rnum 89292-RH_EA_TEST_1_P1_Q
rnum "123 abc 456 efg"
```